# Websockets - Tomcat+Spring+ActiveMQ vs ActiveMQ on its own

Tags: spring, tomcat, websocket, activemq-classic

After creating a websockets server/client implementation with Spring 4.1 using a simple broker, I wanted to add a Messaging Queue to it using the advanced broker.

But on investigating ActiveMQ I find it already has built in websocket support.

So my question is, does anyone know any data/information that will allow me to assess one method over the other.

i.e. What benefits are there of implementing websockets via a Tomcat/Spring stack connected to ActiveMQ, when I could just use ActiveMQ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ActiveMQ is actually Jetty + Spring + "ActiveMQ core", so the difference in implementation is only minor.

Non the less, the web socket support in ActiveMQ is tailor made to suit ActiveMQ and expose some of the built in protocols over Web Socket (STOMP and MQTT). Maybe you want the web socket to have special authentication, access to database sources or other custom logic. That could probably be added to ActiveMQ using the built-in Camel, but some things might be "harder" than doing it inside a plain spring app.

If you want "custom behavior", then a custom Spring app is the way to go. If you are fine with the OOTB behavior of ActiveMQ - lucky you, just download and run.